# Bypassing World Menu with shortcuts

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Is it possible to open the tools in world menu using shortcuts ?

I am interested especially for Workspace , Browser (without selecting a message) , Finder , Monticello and of course all the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On OSX you have (on Windows and Linux you might change Cmd to Ctrl or Alt I never remember):

- Monticello: Cmd+O,P
- Workspace: Cmd+O,W
- Browser: Cmd+O,B
- Transcript: Cmd+O,T
- Settings: Cmd+O,S
- Test Runner: Cmd+O,U

AFAIK there is no shortcut for the Finder, we can assign it Cmd+O,F.

Comment: Uhm, that is Cmd+o,Cmp+p